# How handle Javascript cookies in angular 7 server side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cookies, server-side-rendering

For better SEO, I have implemented SSR in my angular 7 project and i have used javascript cookies  to store login info. The project runs fine but after a awhile there will be error. I have ngOnInit() which perform following operation.

```
if (this.cookiesService.getCookie("user")) {
  if (JSON.parse(this.cookiesService.getCookie("user")).image) {
    return environment.IMGURL + JSON.parse(this.cookiesService.getCookie("user")).image;
  } else {
    return "./assets/images/blank-profile.png";
  }
}
```

Following is the error that shows up

```
2020-10-02 12:21:36ERROR Error: NotYetImplemented
2020-10-02 12:21:36at Document.module.exports.exports.nyi (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:89996:9)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at CookiesService.module.exports../src/app/Services/cookie.service.ts.CookiesService.getCookie (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:161189:46)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at HeaderComponent.module.exports../src/app/shared/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ProfileImage (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:172738:33)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at HeaderComponent.module.exports../src/app/shared/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:172667:14)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:25409:19)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:26673:20)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at checkAndUpdateNode (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:26635:16)
2020-10-02 12:21:36at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:27176:5)
2020-10-02 12:21:07ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
2020-10-02 12:21:07at CanonicalService.module.exports../src/app/Services/canonical.service.ts.CanonicalService.createLinkForCanonicalURL (/var/app/tr-frontend/dist/server.js:160955:9)
```

Is there any solution for this?